# How to post a comment in a wordpress website, using the wordpress REST API, in android

Tags: php, android, wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api

I have been developing an android application to view and comment on posts of my website. Getting posts is easy using GET requests. I cannot post comments though, as it is a POST request which requires authentication. I want Google sign so that users can comment on a post on their phones. How do I use the wordpress REST api to do so. Documentation for the REST API and commenting are mentioned here.

https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1.1/post/sites/%24site/posts/%24post_ID/replies/new/